# ASP.NET MVC Customising The Error Message For A Particular Numeric Property (DataAnnotations?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a OrderNumber model property with a type of double? and I want to change the default "The value 'abc' is not valid for Order Number." error message generated when alpha-numeric (or other invalid) data is entered for it, however I want to do this only for the OrderNumber properties in my model object.  I've tried using a regex data annotation but this only works (with regard to the custom error message) on the client-side validation as, on the server-side, the data fails on the base property data-type (not being a double?) before the regex annotation kicks in.  For some forms we have a lot of input objects and so we have to disable the client-side scripting as it causes speed issues, plus some of our clients will have scripting disabled, so we need to have this custom error message working on the server-side.  How can I set a custom error message if the data type inputted is incorrect?

This also needs to be compatible with localisation (for example, my display label annotation is [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Localisation.Resources), Name = "OrderNumberLabel")] )

Comment: Can't you derive your own validator class for that? In there you can handle even client-side validation (when needed).

Comment: That's, really, what I'm after - the trouble is, ideally, I want that to stay as a double? type property, otherwise it almost makes the validation semi-pointless - I've seen suggestions to make it a string then validate it again and convert to a double? in the controller, but that doesn't seem great idea - and the trouble is it's the input data to property type-conversion that seems to kick in first of all, and this is my problem.

Comment: I guess it's just an opinion but the question may be: is it a "double?" type? After all you're modeling UI so you're talking _about_ users. If they _understand_ what an empty field is and when it has a value it's a floating point number then I think the answer is "YES, keep it as double?" and do whatever you may need to do.

Comment: The users haven't got a clue, in some cases, hence the desire for the custom error message.  It's a double type so it maps to a database column in our system, it's nullable as it's an optional search field.  I've strongly typed it as it makes life a lot easier and, I think, safer - the framework then validates the typing of the input, I can put min/max values in data annotations for range validation, I don't have to convert it, manually (and, hence, write "secondary" validation code, in case somehow it's got through with a text value), when it's used to search - there's all sorts of advantages

Comment: Then keep it as double? and derive your own validation class (if standard one doesn't fit what you need). I think coherence is a good target whenever possible it saves you from terrible headaches...

Comment: Aha, indeed - this is my query, need to work out how to do this (assuming I can't override the default data type-error message) so that this kicks in before the data-type check, or if I can extend the data-type checking code to allow a custom error.

Comment: Thanks - unless I'm misunderstanding them, won't a validator still kick in (or, rather, never be invoked) after the double? data-type binding error occurs?  If there's a way around this, have you got any links to examples, please?

Comment: Usually I take a look at source code of a close attribute (System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RangeAttribute). If you do not want to download sources you can use Reflector (or something like that).

Comment: Isn't the problem still a timing issue - even if I create something similar to the RangeAttribute data annotation validator, won't this still only execute after the data-type has been "validated" (i.e. that it's a double or empty).  So if I enter "ABC" the error will be thrown before any data annotation validator code is executed?

Comment: I guess I really didn't understand your question! You may use a custom TypeDescriptor to do the proper conversion overriding default behavior.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself quite clearly enough - the trouble is that, generally, when I have a problem it's a real git of a problem, haha (an old ERP tech support dept always used to groan when I called them and used to escalate me instantly) - thanks, I'll look into that to see if it solves my problem.

Comment: :) You welcome! I had to re-read all posts and yes, I think a custom TypeDescriptor could be a good start point (so you can provide your own conversion from System.String to System.Double?, handling null or invalid strings.

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved by setting DefaultModelBinder ResourceClassKey property,

Create a "App_GlobalResources" folder under your application and add a resource file. (lets name it as "MyResource.resx").

Now add a key "PropertyValueInvalid" and assign your errorTemplate.(e.g "Invalid content {0} for property {1}").

It should look like..

[image]

Now add the following line in "Application_Start" in global.asax

```
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "MyResource";
```

Now you will see the customized error.(For Non JS)

[image]

Comment: The problem is that will affect _every_ error message, not just the ones for the specified properties - it wouldn't make a lot of sense having an "The order number is invalid, please enter only the numbers from it" message on an order line field.  I _did_ mention that this, above - or is there a way of doing that just for certain, specified properties?

Comment: Then the only way would be to declare it as string in Model, have a regex check for numbers [\d]+, then you can specify what error message you want. PropertyValueInvalid is mainly for numeric types.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to get away from strongly-typing my data as it adds in unnecessary extra complication and code/properties - I have already experimented with changing the property to OrderNumberText, validating it with a regex then having a get-only property OrderNumber as a double? returning a value (so I don't have to change much code, only the input view field for the original OrderNumber) - this still keeps it within the model object, but it's still a bit messy